# Thumbnail view not working properly with custom Master page

Tags: css, thumbnail

The Picture library thumbnail view is not working properly after applied our custom Master page.

It is the expected outcome (with Seattle Master page):
[image]

It is the outcomes of custom Master page. The behaviour is random. By pressing F5 to refresh the page, the 5 thumbnail will switching randomly between shrinked and non-shrinked view. It will not happening on Seattle Master page.
[image][image]

Why is that and which part I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I would check how the css looks like when you experience the problem. Maybe there is something in there that cause this issue.

There could be several issues to this:

- One Script throws and exception
- CSS: Positioning malfunctioning
- CSS: Custom paddings / margins

You can remove the style sheet from the custom master page and check if everything could be displayed properly.